# How to enable/disable specific ReSharper feature

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, resharper

How to enable/disable ReSharper(?) feature on screenshot?

[image]

Visual Studio 2013,
ReSharper 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 answers to this question: the first one is WHY??? This feature allows you to `Ctrl+Left Click` (or by selecting **Go to Definition** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in IDEA keyboard scheme, <kbd>F12</kbd> in Visual Studio keyboard scheme), it asks you where you want to go: either to the `List.cshtml` view (deduced by the `List()` action inside your controller), or to the definition of the `base.View()` method, which will be decompiled automatically by ReSharper (if you have decompilation enabled in ReSharper Options).

If in any event you want turn off those features for ASP.NET MVC, you can do this in ReSharper Options by going to **Code Editing → ASP.NET → MVC**, and unchecking **Enable ASP.NET MVC References**. Please note that this will disable ReSharper's enhancement of all ASP.NET MVC elements - HtmlHelpers in ActionLinks, etc.

Comment: This option no longer seems to be present. Any idea where it's hidden on newer versions?